# Why is this batch code not working?

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I've got this code which I've written in a .bat file, which worked perfectly, but suddenly... it just stopped working, I have no idea what happened to it other than me changing a few folder names.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off  
start /w Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-net-6.6.5.msi  
echo MySQL Connector/NET 6.6.5 has been installed.  
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`cscript desktop.vbs`) DO SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i  
copy Files\DayZAdminApp.exe %DESKTOPDIR%\DayZ Admin Panel  
echo.  
echo DayZ Admin Panel has been placed onto your desktop.  
echo D | xcopy Files\DaRT %desktopdir%\DayZ Admin Panel\Files\DaRT /E /Q  
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 >nul: 2>nul:  
echo.  
echo DayZ Admin rCon Tool (DaRT) has been copied.  
echo.  
copy Files\loadout.exe %DESKTOPDIR%\DayZ Admin Panel\Files  
echo Loadout editor has been copied.  
echo.  
echo.  
echo Make sure you keep the folder intact, any missing files will limit the panel's capabilities.  
echo.  
pause
```

And here's the desktop.vbs file:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")  
wscript.echo(strDesktop)`
```

and in case it helps, here's a screenshot of the output:

[image: code output]

Note: My code worked just fine when it was exactly the same except for the foldernames `Files\` and `DayZ Admin Panel\`

If it's me just mucking up those foldernames, please tell me what I did wrong, because this looks pretty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"` around your paths, since the contain spaces

```
copy Files\DayZAdminApp.exe "%DESKTOPDIR%\DayZ Admin Panel"
...
echo D | xcopy Files\DaRT "%desktopdir%\DayZ Admin Panel\Files\DaRT" /E /Q
...
copy Files\loadout.exe "%DESKTOPDIR%\DayZ Admin Panel\Files"
```

Comment: Right... I'm an idiot, aren't I? Can't believe I forgot about that

Answer (score 2):

You have to use quotes whenever paths have spaces: `"%desktopdir%\DayZ Admin Panel\Files\DaRT"`

Comment: happens even in the best families :-)

Comment: I'm just going to throw out the "it's 12:30am & I only slept for 3 hours last night" excuse here :>

Answer (score -1):

You not need VBScript assistance in this case, but looks like you have problem with redirecting the output of an executable into a batch variable, therefore I made a piece of code with hope it w'd helps in similar tasks.

```
@Echo OFF

Echo --- Test 1 ---
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (cscript desktop.vbs) DO (
   SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i
)
Echo %DESKTOPDIR%

Echo --- Test 2 ---
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (%windir%\system32\cscript.exe desktop.vbs) DO (
   SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i
)
Echo %DESKTOPDIR%

Pause
```

Output: 
[image]

And correct one one s'd be:

```
@ECHO OFF

Echo --- Test 1 ---
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('cscript.exe desktop.vbs') DO (
   SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i
)
ECHO Desktop: %DESKTOPDIR%

REM or...

Echo --- Test 2 ---
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (`cscript.exe desktop.vbs`) DO (
   SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i
)
Echo Desktop: %DESKTOPDIR%

Pause
```

Comment: Nope, the vbscript works just fine, it just gets the full path for the user's desktop, i.e C:\Users\Name\Desktop, localisation can change that path to C:\Gebruikers\Name\Bureaublad (for NL versions) etc, or some people have their Windows on their D:\ or E:\ drives for example. That's what the vbscript is for in my case.

Comment: Probably you edited your code, not sure, as now it looks closer to my Test 2, but for sure you can get desktop path without VBS using `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` ;-)

Comment: As I said, in non-English versions of Windows, "Desktop" could be "Bureablad" in Dutch, or "Skrivbord" in Swedish (not sure if that's the actual name for it, but you get the point)